# How can I get my server to execute (instead of displaying source for) PHP?

Tags: php, apache-2.4, configuration, installation

I am having trouble getting PHP to be executed instead of treated like plain text.

I'm on a new Debian 10 development server, and have installed e.g. `apache2` and `libapache2-mod-php`, which installed `libapache2-mod-php7.3`, but `a2enmod` is not finding a PHP module to execute. `/etc/apache2/mods-available` has:

```
access_compat.load    dir.conf          proxy_express.load
actions.conf          dir.load          proxy_fcgi.load
actions.load          dump_io.load      proxy_fdpass.load
alias.conf        echo.load         proxy_ftp.conf
alias.load        env.load          proxy_ftp.load
allowmethods.load     expires.load      proxy_hcheck.load
asis.load         ext_filter.load       proxy_html.conf
auth_basic.load       file_cache.load       proxy_html.load
auth_digest.load      filter.load       proxy_http2.load
auth_form.load        headers.load      proxy_http.load
authn_anon.load       heartbeat.load        proxy.load
authn_core.load       heartmonitor.load     proxy_scgi.load
authn_dbd.load        http2.conf        proxy_uwsgi.load
authn_dbm.load        http2.load        proxy_wstunnel.load
authn_file.load       ident.load        ratelimit.load
authn_socache.load    imagemap.load     reflector.load
authnz_fcgi.load      include.load      remoteip.load
authnz_ldap.load      info.conf         reqtimeout.conf
authz_core.load       info.load         reqtimeout.load
authz_dbd.load        lbmethod_bybusyness.load  request.load
authz_dbm.load        lbmethod_byrequests.load  rewrite.load
authz_groupfile.load  lbmethod_bytraffic.load   sed.load
authz_host.load       lbmethod_heartbeat.load   session_cookie.load
authz_owner.load      ldap.conf         session_crypto.load
authz_user.load       ldap.load         session_dbd.load
autoindex.conf        log_debug.load        session.load
autoindex.load        log_forensic.load     setenvif.conf
brotli.load       lua.load          setenvif.load
buffer.load       macro.load        slotmem_plain.load
cache_disk.conf       md.load           slotmem_shm.load
cache_disk.load       mime.conf         socache_dbm.load
cache.load        mime.load         socache_memcache.load
cache_socache.load    mime_magic.conf       socache_shmcb.load
cern_meta.load        mime_magic.load       speling.load
cgid.conf         mpm_event.conf        ssl.conf
cgid.load         mpm_event.load        ssl.load
cgi.load          mpm_prefork.conf      status.conf
charset_lite.load     mpm_prefork.load      status.load
data.load         mpm_worker.conf       substitute.load
dav_fs.conf       mpm_worker.load       suexec.load
dav_fs.load       negotiation.conf      unique_id.load
dav.load          negotiation.load      userdir.conf
dav_lock.load         proxy_ajp.load        userdir.load
dbd.load          proxy_balancer.conf   usertrack.load
deflate.conf          proxy_balancer.load   vhost_alias.load
deflate.load          proxy.conf        xml2enc.load
dialup.load       proxy_connect.load
```

PHP does not appear to me to be listed.

Are there other steps besides installing Apache, PHP, and the Apache PHP library to be able to `a2enmod` PHP?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the following commands after you checked Apache worked?

- sudo apt update
- sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php

And did you restart Apache after the install?

- sudo systemctl restart apache2

This was all I had to do to make it work on Debian 10.

**Test**

Put a file named index.php in your server web-root. It should contain this:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Then open a web browser and point it to your server.

If php works you should now see a whole lot more than what you put in the file.

Comment: Thank you; yes, I did. `mods-available` still has no matches for `*php*`.

Comment: What version of php is installed, and which version of libapache2-mod-php? Do a php --version on the command line.

Comment: Please check that libapache2-mod-php is really installed. Files in mods-available are provided by this package, you can check it with
apt-file search /etc/apache2/mods-available/php*

Please post list of installed PHP related packages
apt list --installed | grep php